# Actionscript 2.0 give an object 3D rotation?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I have a function but it doens't work the way i want it to. I want the objects rotation to rotate around the y-axis, so that it looks 3D ish.

```
_root.HealthBar._rotation._y = angle;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are talking about AS2 and the stage is 2D, there is only one rotation, i.e. there is no separate rotations for x and y.

All you would do is;

```
_root.HealthBar._rotation = angle;
```